# Unable to compile doctest's `CHECK_THROWS_AS` with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, doctest

Consider the following code using [`doctest.h`](https://github.com/doctest/doctest/) C++ unit test library:

```cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include "doctest.h"
TEST_CASE("") {
    CHECK_THROWS_AS(throw 0, int);
}
```

The code creates a single test case with an empty name. The test ensures that `throw 0` throws an exception of type `int`. The example compiles and runs successfully on GCC.

However, compiling with Visual Studio 2019 yields an error:

```
[REDACTED]>cl /std:c++17 a.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30142.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

a.cpp
a.cpp(4): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
```

How do I fix it?

At the same time, a simpler example compiles and works as expected:

```cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include "doctest.h"
TEST_CASE("") {
    CHECK(2 * 2 == 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual C++ command line compiler does not fully support C++ exceptions by default, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160#default-exception-handling-behavior). Hence, [doctest disables them inside](https://github.com/doctest/doctest/blob/7b9885133108ae301ddd16e2651320f54cafeba7/doctest/doctest.h#L277-L279) (`_CPPUNWIND` is left undefined by VS), but the error message [is somewhat misleading](https://github.com/doctest/doctest/issues/633).

You should pass the `/EHsc` compiler flag:

```
[REDACTED]>cl /EHsc /std:c++17 a.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30142.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

a.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30142.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:a.exe
a.obj
```

As a sidenote, both Visual Studio's default "Empty project" and [CMake configurations](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/efcf3a46f786c665ed2bc0923f344e4d03af51fa/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake#L240) include this flag by default:

[image]